# CSS and Javascript not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

i am new to CSS and JS.

I am trying to put a 'slider bar' in a page, following this instruction http://jsfiddle.net/juanmendez/v9zkB/. And i put the html, js, css file in the same directory. then i include the js and CSS source in html head as below (also, i included bootstrap files):

```
<head>
  <title>test_slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider_test.css" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="slider_test.js"></script>
</head>
```

But there is not effect on html page from the js or css.

Comment: What error are you seeing in your console?

Comment: Does the page have a body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Twitter Bootstrap include jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526594/does-twitter-bootstrap-include-jquery)

Comment: Why so many downvotes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanmendez/v9zkB/) on the left side, where it says **Frameworks & Extensions** you can see jQuery dependency loaded

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jquery library in your header. Add this inside your header before any scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Didn't see your answer mpa4Hu. But yeah, make sure you add the jquery library BEFORE any other scripts

Basically, it should look like this:

```
  <head>
  <title>test_slider</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">   </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider_test.css" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="slider_test.js"></script>
 </head>
```