# Which CDN to include to use Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap via including CDN. According to the documentation, there are three:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I know that I should include CSS (the 1st) and JavaScript (the 3rd). But do I also need to include JQuery CDN? Or it is already included in Bootstrap CDN?

And what is the optional theme CDN (the 2nd)? Is it necessary to include it if I what to use Bootstrap?

```
**EDIT:**
```

Now since I know that I should include JQuery separately, the main problem is:

> And what is the optional theme CDN (the 2nd)? Is it necessary to
>   include it if I what to use Bootstrap?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you need to include even jquery.

Comment: did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526594/does-twitter-bootstrap-include-jquery

Comment: @SpringLearner thank you! But what is the optional them CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme is as it says optional.

It serves as an example of how to theme bootstrap after including the core files.

So you want to include the

- Core css,
- jQuery from either the cdnjs or google cdn
- Core js

Then have your own locally stored css file with your changes in it that would go in the same place as the theme in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must need to include jquery via CDN or from your server.

I prefer [google jQuery CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) which is obviously fast and less chances for network(B'cos of Googles popularity)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you can use [Cdn js](https://cdnjs.com/) which provides all javascript libraries CDN.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what is the optional theme CND? Is it necessary if I want to use Bootstrap?